# Abbreviation for Foley

Tags: foley

Real quick question:

What's the convention for abbreviating "Foley" in naming a track?

FLY?
FOL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

We typically layout foley in two groups: FS (or Feet) and Props, with each group being between 8-16 tracks wide.

Comment: Do you add a 3rd group of cloth or is this included in props?

Comment: @Marco, normally cloth is on its own track separate from FS and props.

Answer (score 1):

we just spell it out FWIW.  Foly1, Foly2, etc.

Comment: Cool thx ;)     .


Answer (score 1):

I typically use F or FOL as a general Abbreviation.

F_Steps - Self Explanatory
F_Cloth - Also Self Explanatory
F_Props or F_Inc for Foley Props or "Incedental" sounds like hand props or anything non-steps or cloth.

Answer (score 0):

I just have 16 tracks simply called Foley 1 - 16. First 8 tracks feet, last 7 tracks spots, with the final track being cloth moves. I name the regions I record with abbreviations; FTS, MOVES etc.